# How do you show independence of a pair of two random variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Let U~U(0,1) and determine if a pair of random variables are independent.  Verify your claim using simulation in MATLAB.  I have multiple pairs of random variables on various intervals within (0,1).  Some are independent and some are dependent.  I computed the correct probabilities to determine this.  I do not know how to verify in MATLAB though.  I do not have code yet because my question lies in how such a verification is done.

Do I call on rand many times and tally how many times the values fall within the bounds of each random variable and make a histogram?  Or do I make a plot of various values ranging from (0,1) and show how the two random variables act at each value?  Any type of suggestions will help get me started please!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. I think https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this. But do check their help center to make sure your question is on-topic there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok.  Thank you!  I assumed a MATLAB question would be welcome here; there is a well-used MATLAB tag.  I should only come here with specific coding questions?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Once you find out *how* you want to verify this, and if you have trouble implementing that in code, then you can come here. Your question right now has nothing to do with MATLAB, as far as I can tell.